# How to fix error "Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, redux, axios

So I am getting this error when trying to delete an education/experience field, in the webapp. But when I press to delete, it throws me an error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined
```

And it happens when It tries to send a payload. Here is the code, that causes the error:

```
  161 | } catch (err) {
  162 |   dispatch({
  163 |     type: PROFILE_ERROR,
> 164 |     payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
  165 | ^    });
  166 |   console.log(err.response);
  167 | }
```

Here is the actions file for the delete:

```
export const deleteEducation = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = axios.await(`/api/profile/education/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Education Deleted', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
    console.log(err.response);
  }
};
```

Here is the API code for the delete funtion:

```
// @route   DELETE api/profile/:edu_id
// @desc    Delete education from profile
//@access  Private
router.delete('/education/:edu_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
    const removeIndex = profile.education
      .map((item) => item.id)
      .indexOf(req.params.edu_id);
    profile.education.splice(removeIndex, 1);

    await profile.save();
    res.json({ msg: 'Education Deleted' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

I'm having really hard time understanding redux, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Well, usually errors like this mean that you're trying to access attributes of an object that doesn't exist, so first I would print the error object to see what it does have. Try logging the object before the line of the error.

Comment: `err.response` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actions File for the delete

replace the 3rd Line with

`` const res = await axios.delete(`/api/profile/education/${id}`); ``